# How to make a file input field in form?

Tags: android, input

I am working on an android app. In the app, the user needs to attach an image file in form.

How do I make an image file input field in my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default FileChooser api in android like java. So you can create your own. Or you can use any of these open source projects and modify according to your need

1. [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)
2. [android-FileChooser](https://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/)